# Network limited in dorm but I have password

Tags: windows, ethernet

So I just moved into dorm and I received username/password for my internet connection. When I plug in ethernet cable I got Ethernet and under it Limited so I suppose I should enter username/pass somehow but I can't get to that point. When I click on it nothing happens. I am using windows 8.1 and would be really gratefull if someone couold help

Comment: There is no way to know the specific method your dorm uses. Contact the manager or IT help desk. I'm sure there's a ready-made pamphlet available.

Comment: This is correct answer, I got paper with explanation only it is on German so it took me some time to translate it.

Comment: @DanielB, may be best move your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well then, here's the *official* solution. ;)

There is no (universally valid) way to know the specific authentication method a network uses. Contact the manager or IT help desk. They'll surely have a guide available.